# Different column number in rows

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I would like to create a table like this:

```
| H1   |           h2           | <--- is centered vertically
| T1   |                        |
| T1   |   text  | text  | text |
| T1   |   text     |      text |
| T1   | text |text | text|text |
```

How can I do so? mainly the problem is with row 2.

Working example but not centering correctly the row with 5 columns

```
\begin{table}[!hbt]
   \centering
   \caption{caption} \label{tab:table} 
   \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
      \toprule
      xxxxxxx & \multicolumn{12}{c}{yyyyyyyyyyyyyy} \\
      \midrule
      aaaaaaa & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{bbbbbbbbbbbbbb}} \\
      $E=\lambda \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{} \\
      \midrule
      cccccccc & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{fffffffffffffff} \\
      $P=\beta \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)}\\
      gggggggggg & \multicolumn{3}{c}{gggggggg} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ddddddddd} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ggggggggg} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{dsdsdsds}  \\
      $I=\gamma \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)} \\
      Calidad canal & \multicolumn{4}{c}{aaaaaaaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} \\
      $\Delta = \delta \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} \\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You need to actually create 7 columns and then make appropriate spans.

Comment: The only solution I've found is using a table with the minimum common multiple of the columns. In this case it would be a 13 columns table, and then merge columns.

Comment: Do you have a MWE that we can look at?

Comment: To get the columns to have equal width, try doing this with `tabularx`; cf. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60601/evenly-distributing-column-widths).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following provides a much cleaner interface, if you're interested in spreading out the contents beyond column 1 evenly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,multirow,tabularx}
\newcommand{\makecell}[2][@{}c@{}]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X}
  \toprule
  xxxxxxx & 
    \hfill yyyyyyyyyyyyyy \hfill\null \\
  \midrule
  \makecell{aaaaaaa \\ $E = \lambda \cdot x$} & 
    \hfill bbbbbbbbbbbbbb \hfill\null \\
  \midrule
  \makecell{cccccccc \\ $P = \beta \cdot x$} & 
    \hfill \makecell{ddddddddddddddddddd \\ (4)} 
    \hfill \makecell{eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee \\ (3)} 
    \hfill \makecell{fffffffffffffff \\ (1)} \hfill\null \\
  \makecell{gggggggggg \\ $I = \gamma \cdot x$} & 
    \hfill \makecell{gggggggg \\ (6)} 
    \hfill \makecell{ddddddddd \\ (5)} 
    \hfill \makecell{ggggggggg \\ (3)} 
    \hfill \makecell{dsdsdsds \\ (1)} \hfill\null \\
  \makecell{Calidad canal \\ $\Delta = \delta \cdot x$} & 
    \hfill \makecell{aaaaaaaaaaaa \\ (5)} 
    \hfill \makecell{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh \\ (3)} 
    \hfill \makecell{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr \\ (1)} \hfill\null \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The entire structure is set in a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) consisting of two columns. The second `X`-column removes the guesswork of trying to figure out how many columns to use and how wide the table should be. `\hfill`s spread the content evenly within the column, while `\makecell` (similar in definition to that provided by the [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell)) stacks elements vertically.

The above code is clean and allows customization by changing the definition of `\makecell` (if needed).

Comment: Not only a beautiful solution, but also one minimalizing (formal) number of colums.

Answer (score 4):

To vertically center the H2 cell, you will need to also use the `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c }
  H1 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{H2}} \\
  T1 \\
  T1 & test & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text} & text \\
  T1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text} \\
  T1 & text & text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}
```

This code will produce:

[image]

To make the row with 3 text's have evenly sized tables, I assumed 13 cells would be required. However, the sizing was still unusual until I added a row of blank cells to the bottom.

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c c c }
  H1 & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{H2}} \\
  T1 \\
  T1 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{text} \\
  T1 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{text} \\
  T1 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\end{tabular}
```

This produces:

[image: 13 column table]

Comment: I reached the same solution and have the same problem, as you can see for the MWE I just put

Comment: Ah,  yes. You must have posted that while I was editing.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few wrong `\multicolumn` commands in your code.

Hope this is what you wanted

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
   \centering
   \caption{caption} \label{tab:table}
   \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
      \toprule
      xxxxxxx & \multicolumn{12}{c}{yyyyyyyyyyyyyy} \\
      \midrule
      aaaaaaa & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{bbbbbbbbbbbbbb}} \\
      $E=\lambda \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{} \\
      \midrule
      cccccccc & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{fffffffffffffff} \\
      $P=\beta \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)}\\
      gggggggggg & \multicolumn{2}{c}{gggggggg} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ddddddddd} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ggggggggg} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dsdsdsds}  \\
      $I=\gamma \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} \\
      Calidad canal & \multicolumn{4}{c}{aaaaaaaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} \\
      $\Delta = \delta \cdot x$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} \\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```