# How to spread columns evenly without fixing table width?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The answers on how to spread table columns evenly under a multicolumn seem to suggest that this is not possible, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60604/36836. It seems hard to believe that LaTeX has this restriction.

Here is an example showing the basic problem of spreading columns evenly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{some longer text here}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule
some text here  & A    & B   & C   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The last column, 3, take more space than the other columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try updating your source as follows. Change the position of column 3. Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccl}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{some longer text here}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule
some text here  & A    & B   & C   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Edit as per the comment. You can set the values in the tabular position environment as per your requirements. A sample have been shown below. Sorry for the late reply.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{some longer text here}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule
some text here  & A    & B   & C   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's better than the original but then there is still a large chunk of empty space. I'd prefer the distribution of space evenly.

Comment: Okay. Check my recent edit.

Comment: Great but not perfect because now one needs to set the column width manually, which is close to setting the table with manually.

Comment: A small improvement of your code to get closer to the original's alignment is to add `\usepackage{array}` and use as column alignment `l>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Daniel. I will check your suggested command for sure.

Comment: I guess the answer answers my question because I was not specific enough. So, I'll set it as the answer. Maybe I'll try to ask a more precise question later on.

Comment: Or even nicer `l *{3}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}`.

Comment: Or with `wc{1cm}` to ease centering.

Comment: @TeXnician: By "ease centering" you mean "center the content independently of the cell's width by overprinting", right? And `wc{1cm}` is a shortcut for `w{c}{1cm}`.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, exactly. If the cell's content is short you can use the `w` type to avoid the need for centering (and correctives like arraybackslash).

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem was putting LaTeX commands in front of `\toprule`.

Note that you only have to use `\makebox` in one row to establish the widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newsavebox\tempbox
\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{some longer text here}% measure width
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\dimen0=\dimexpr \wd\tempbox/3 - 4\tabcolsep/3\relax
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\usebox\tempbox}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & \makebox[\dimen0]{1} & \makebox[\dimen0]{2} & \makebox[\dimen0]{3}\\
\midrule
some text here  & A    & B   & C   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: replacing  ` \divide\dimen0 by 3\\ ` works---but now how to insert text in the first row which remains blank

Comment: Oops, must use global box.  Weird!

Comment: I get the crash too. But don't know why.

Comment: @daniel - The bug is going into an infinite loop rather than catching the problem.  Using \hline instead of \toprule gives a improper \noalign error message.