# Cannot make the columns evenly distributed. What's the reason?

Tags: tables, debugging

Dear experienced friends,

I met a strange bug when I tried to draw a table. As shown in the picture, I wish I can make all the columns `4,5,6,1,2,3` evenly distributed. However, the width of `6` is always larger than others. May I ask why this bug happens, and how can I fix it? Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{2pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}


\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\scalebox{1}{

 \begin{tabular}{c  c  c  c @{\extracolsep{0.2cm}} c  c  c} 
 \toprule
 \multirow{2}{4em}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Cubic Height Height} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Width Width}\\[1ex]
 
 \cmidrule{2-4}
 \cmidrule{5-7}
 
 Model & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ [1ex]
 
 \midrule
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 
 B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 
 C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 
 \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}}

\caption{Comparison}
\label{table 2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

( I also tried `\begin{tabular}{p{3.2cm}  p{0.8cm}  p{0.8cm}  p{0.8cm} @{\extracolsep{0.15cm}} p{0.8cm}  p{0.8cm}  p{0.8cm}}`, but it didn't work. )

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: One approach that does not require manually specifying column width is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515973/250119 or the linked question there (basically such a solution  *must* measure things. There's also a solution there using the new package `tabularray`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a fixed column width -- the `c` column type does not have an ex ante fixed width. Since you're using the `array` package, you could use its `w` column type, with a width of 8mm or more, for this purpose. (Aside: I came up with `8mm` via trial and error.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l *{6}{w{c}{8mm}} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Cubic Height Height} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Width Width}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 Model & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\midrule
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison}\label{table 2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer perfectly solved my problem! Thank you so much, Mico! May I ask a follow-up question? Does `{l *{6}{w{c}{8mm}} }` means that you set 6 left-aligned cells, and all of them are 8mm width? What if I want to set the first one as a 5mm center-aligned one? Should I use `{c *{1}{w{c}{5mm}} | l *{5}{w{c}{8mm}} }`? Thank you!

Comment: @NickChen - You're most welcome. The table has 7 columns in total. `l` denotes "variable-width left-aligned", `*{6}{...}` means "6 times {...}, and `w{c}{8mm}` denotes "fixed-width (8mm wide) centered". If you want the first column to be exactly 5mm wide and center-aligned, you'd replace `l` with `w{c}{5mm}`. "Variable-width" means "as wide as the widest cell in that column"; in the present case, that's the width of the word "Model". More information about the `w` column type may be found in the user guide of the [array])https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I just tried it on my script and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot, Mico!