# Problems with columns evenly spaced

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn, columns

I have the following example code, and I want all the columns to have the same width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\title{dd}
\author{david.moldes }
\date{June 2023}

\begin{document}

 
\end{table}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Levels}}\\
\cmidrule{2-8} \
\textbf{Factors} & \textit{1} & \textit{2} & \textit{3} & \textit{4} & \textit{5} & \textit{6} & \textit{7}\\ \midrule
\textit{A} & Water & ChCl:2Gly & ChCl:2Urea & --- 
 & ---   & ---   & ---  \\
\textit{B}& 0 & 0.40 & 0.57 &0.69 & 0.82 & 0.86 & 0.91 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I tried to use the explanation given here, [How to spread columns evenly without fixing table width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515963/how-to-spread-columns-evenly-without-fixing-table-width?noredirect=1&lq=1), but in a beamer document it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Uncentered columns

The `tabularx` package provides a column type `X` to automatically adjust the width of the columns to a suitable one (ultimately, equating the width of the columns of this type).

### Code

```latex
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{@{} l *7{X} @{}}  % I've had to do `1.5\textwidth` as a the width to suit my specific renderer. Adjust it according to your needs.
    \toprule
                        &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Levels}}                                                                         \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    \textbf{Factors}    &   \textit{1}  &   \textit{2}  &   \textit{3}  &   \textit{4}  &   \textit{5}  &   \textit{6}  &   \textit{7}  \\
    \midrule
    \textit{A}          &   Water       &   ChCl:2Gly   &   ChCl:2Urea  &   ---         &   ---         &   ---         &   ---         \\
    \textit{B}          &   0           &   0.40        &   0.57        &   0.69        &   0.82        &   0.86        &   0.91        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

### Image

[image: Table with columns of type X (uncentered)]

## Centered columns

Although, every column of type `X` is automatically left-aligned. To keep them centered, use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932) answer (from another tex stackexchange post).

### New code

```latex
% \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}  % in your preamble

\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{@{} l *7{Y} @{}}  % I've had to do `1.5\textwidth` as a the width to suit my specific renderer. Adjust it according to your needs.
    \toprule
                        &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Levels}}                                                                         \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    \textbf{Factors}    &   \textit{1}  &   \textit{2}  &   \textit{3}  &   \textit{4}  &   \textit{5}  &   \textit{6}  &   \textit{7}  \\
    \midrule
    \textit{A}          &   Water       &   ChCl:2Gly   &   ChCl:2Urea  &   ---         &   ---         &   ---         &   ---         \\
    \textit{B}          &   0           &   0.40        &   0.57        &   0.69        &   0.82        &   0.86        &   0.91        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

### New image

[image: Table with columns of type X (centered)]

Hope this is what you were looking for!