# xltabular \centering\arraybackslash}X alignment breaks with 20 or more columns

Tags: column-width, xltabular

I am generating dynamicaly big tables (hundreds of rows and dozens of columns) from python/jinja.
I found some solution to make 'subcolumns' widths even:
[Evenly distributing column widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60601/evenly-distributing-column-widths)

So I defined column type:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

the problem is that when number of 'Y' columns reaches 20 the whole table becomes a mess.

full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, total={11in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
{
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ |*{19}{Y|} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
    \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{first} & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{second} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{third} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{fourth} &
    \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{fifth} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{sixth} & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{seventh} & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{eighth}
    \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
    a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k & l & m & n & o & p & q & r & s\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
    \hline
    
  \end{xltabular}
}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

In state above with 19 columns the table looks fine:
[image: 19 columns]

but if we add just one more Y column:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ |*{20}{Y|} }
...
```

it turns into:
[image: 20 or more columns]

Adding other types of column like 'c' or 'l' does not affect negatively.

Is there some limit that can be omitted by compiler parameter or something?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use xltabular here. Why don't you use a normal longtable and calculate the width before as something like  (\textwidth-n\tabcolsep)/20 ? It will be much faster and less fragile.

Comment: It is possible that 40\tabcolsep took up all of the available space leaving nothing for the contents.  Try using c columns and standalone to see just how much space you will need.

Comment: If I remove the option `total={11in, 8in}`, I am unable to reproduce the issue you're experiencing after adding a 20th column.

Comment: It would be more useful to provide an example of the problem rather than having  to guess how to add a extra colum, where do you span the headings? Also I wrote `tabularx` but I'd never use it for such a table. `tabularx` is all about adjusting line breaking within cells to control the total width and you have no line breaking here.